# cost function in tensorflow using "sum" of "mean"

Tags: tensorflow

```
# cost/loss function
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(hypothesis - Y))

# cost/loss function
cost = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(hypothesis - Y))
```

why different between "sum" and "mean" in cost function?

some posting using "mean" and some posting using "sum"...

Comment: Please rephrase your question to be more clear. `Sum` and `mean` are different operations and therefore have different behavior. If you mean in a specific context ("some posting using") then you forgot to provide it for us.

Answer (score 0):

Both of these functions reduces the the tensor(array/matrix)  to single element tensor. You can also specify your axis which would be reduced.

Like if you are calculated cross entropy loss in image classification and you are doing your training in batches (while each batch have multiple examples) then for each example you would get a loss and as a result you would have an array of losses. You can then reduce this array to single number by either taking sum of all the elements of array or by taking average of the array.
For example

```
array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]    #example
reduced_sum = [15] #reducing array using tf.reduce_sum
reduced_mean = [3]  #reducing array using tf.reduce_mean
```

For more information see
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/reduce_mean
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/reduce_sum